# PHP simple Excel lib

Tags: php, excel

I'm looking for a way to do the following:

```
$file = 'file.xls';
$input = '<tr><td>Some input</td></tr>';

if (!file_exists($file))
{
     create_excel($file);  //Create the sheet
     input_titles($file);  //Add column titles
}
else
{
     add_input_to_the_last_line($input);
}
```

Is there a library which can simply do the above?

Comment: Is there a specific need for an .xls file? If you're just wanting data that will open in Excel and don't care about formatting I'd do that with a csv file instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use PHPExcel [library](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/):

### Example Usage:

```
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$rowCount = 1;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A'.$rowCount, <your_row_name>);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('B'.$rowCount, <your_row_name>);
    $rowCount++;
}
$objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007($objPHPExcel);
$objWriter->save('your_file_name.xlsx');
```

Comment: Just giving a file the extension 'xls' and serving it with the mime type of an Excel file doesn't make it an xls file.

Comment: @Braiba  
Could you please justify more on this?

Comment: the file extension and content-type are just hints to the operating system as to how they should treat the data, but you're lying to it with both, because you're pretending that the data you're giving it is in the XLS format, when in fact it's just a tab-separated data file. This is basically like buying an French-to-English dictionary, crossing out the word "French" on the cover and writing in "German" and expecting it to help you read German.

Comment: @Braiba Thanks for the explanation. Made changes to answer accordingly. :-)