# Exported csv files contains html tags

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, csv

I want to create one csv file.

Proble is that generated csv file contains html tag and other useless information.

I have try following code:

```
<?php
    mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    mysql_select_db("XXXXXXX");
    $query = "SELECT * FROM table";
    $filename = $file."_".date("Y-m-d_H-i",time());

   //Generate the CSV file header
   header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
   header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
   header("Content-disposition: csv" . date("Y-m-d") . ".csv");
   header("Content-disposition: filename=".$filename.".csv");

   $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
   $vilaio='';
   $vilaio.="\n\tID\tEmail id\n";
   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
      $vilaio.="\n\t$row[eid_id]\t$row[eid_email]"; 
   }

  print $vilaio;
?>
```

Is there any problem in the code?

Comment: Are the html tags and other useless information not perhaps stored in the database?

Comment: Where are the html tags printed? Between the records you want to display or before or after them?

Answer (score 0):

Try using strip_tags() like below:

```
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$vilaio='';
 $vilaio.="\n\tID\tEmail id\n";
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
      $vilaio.="\n\t$row[eid_id]\t".strip_tags($row[eid_email]); 
 }
print $vilaio;
```

Answer (score 0):

The header way is not receommened way to create one csv file. PHP has a class library called `PHPExcel`.

[PHPExcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/)  library:

Already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11390343/php-simple-excel-lib/11390457#11390457)